# Rsync running check (ps ax) in script differs from manual check

Tags: php, zend-framework, rsync

I know the question "how to check if rsync process is still running?" can be found on a hundred websites, but I can't get around the problem I'm dealing with unfortunately.

So short explanation: I'm doing rsync jobs starting with a button click in a GUI. They run completely in background. Normally, they finish successful, but if they don't, our engineers have to check logs and manually restart everything. Therefore, I'm trying to improve the rsync jobs so they are more robust and give a short and clean explanation in our GUI why they failed and can be restarted easily. Everything is build with Zend Framework.

Now the problem: if for some reason the rsync is interrupted, it keeps looping endlessly. Therefore, I wanted to build in a check if the rsync job is still busy. This I'm doing with following command:

```
ps ax | grep rsync | grep -vq grep; echo &?
```

This will return 0 if an rsync process can be found, 1 if not found. If 1, fail the job in short. Now, sometimes it looks like it have a hick up while copying, the check returns 1 and the job failed. I know that after a second or 2 the rsync job just continues (I don't know why the process suddenly disappears sometimes). So 1 check is not enough and so I'm planning to do multiple checks like for 30 seconds and if after that time the command still doesn't return 0, it's safe to say the job failed. This is the check I'm having right now:

```
// completed?
    if ($newSize == 0 || $oldSize > $newSize) {
        Zend_Registry::get('logger')->debug('Size not equal, copy still busy');
        $cmd = 'ps ax | grep rsync | grep -vq grep; echo $?';
        $output = array();
        Af_Util::executeCommand($cmd, false, $output);
        if ($output[0] == '1') {
            Zend_Registry::get('logger')->debug('Rsync process might be broken! Doing more checks before actually failing the job.');
            $counter = 1;
            do {
                sleep(5);
                Zend_Registry::get('logger')->debug('Check ' . $counter . ':');
                $cmd = 'ps ax | grep rsync | grep -vq grep; echo $?';
                $output2 = array();
                Af_Util::executeCommand($cmd, false, $output2);
                foreach($output2 as $line) {
                    Zend_Registry::get('logger')->debug('Output/line: ' . $line);
                }
                if ($output2[0] == '1') {
                    $counter++;
                }
                else {
                    Zend_Registry::get('logger')->debug('Rsync process seems to be back up again!');
                    break;
                }
            } while ($counter < 6);
            if ($counter == 6) {
                throw new Af_Exception('Rsync process has quit unexpectedly.');
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The problem now is situated in the loop. It keeps returning 1 (not found) EVEN if I manually check at the same time with the same command and get a 0 returned. So there it is... I don't know what's the problem here. Can't figure out why. Everything in the loop looks fine I think. The executeCommand function is here:

```
$this->con = ssh2_connect($host, $port);
function executeCommand($command, $haltOnError=true) {
    Zend_Registry::get('logger')->debug('Af_Ssh::executeCommand(' . $command . ', ' . $haltOnError . ')');
    $stream = ssh2_exec($this->con, $command);

    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);

    $stdout = trim(stream_get_contents($stream));
    $stderr = trim(stream_get_contents(ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR)));


    Zend_Registry::get('logger')->debug('Stdout: ' . $stdout);
    Zend_Registry::get('logger')->debug('Stderr: ' . $stderr);
    if (strlen($stderr) > 0 && $haltOnError == true) {
        throw new Af_Exception('Af_Ssh::executecommand(' . $command . ') failed: ' . $stderr);
    }
    elseif (strlen($stderr)) {
        return $stderr;
    }
    return $stdout;
}
```

and some screenshots:

[logs output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBggd.png)

[logs output continued](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx9MM.png)

[manually executed command at same time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYPW9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what's wrong here, but I found a working solution:

Instead of using:

```
$cmd = 'ps ax | grep rsync | grep -vq grep; echo $?';
$output2 = array();
Af_Util::executeCommand($cmd, false, $output2);
if ($output2[0] == '1') {
```

I changed it to:

```
$cmd = 'ps ax | grep rsync | grep -v grep';
$output2 = array();
$res = Af_Util::executeCommand($cmd, false, $output2);
if ($res == '1') {
```

This works fine.